# ¿Como mostrar tabla oculta en phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Saludos, estoy usando phpmyadmin 4.7.4 y le di en el icono del ojo a un costado del nombre de una tabla, y ahora no encuero la opción para volver a mostrar mi tabla, ¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para volver a mostrar mi tabla ahí?

[image: Ejemplo, captura de pantalla phpmyadmin]

Comment: Al parecer actualmente ya no aparece una bombilla sino un simbolo de ojo al lado derecho del nombre de la base de datos, presionalo y te mostrara las tablas que esten ocultas y solo dale a la opcion de mostrar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando se oculta una tabla, te debe aparecer una bombilla al lado del nombre de la base de datos. Haga clic sobre la bombilla y se abrirá un cuadro de diálogo con las tablas ocultas, lo que le permitirá mostrarlas.

Comment: :O Ya la vi gracias.

Comment: ¿Es posible quitar ese boton?

Answer (score 4):

Despliega la tabla "phpmyadmin" y alli selecciona la "pma_navigationhiding", esta contendrá las tablas que has ocultado, si las borras y pulsas en "Recargar el panel" tendrás de nuevo todas las tablas visibles.